# Does Play Framework support "snippets"?

Tags: java, playframework

If i want to have a common piece of UI across multiple pages, such as a menu, what is the recommended way to do this?

It would contain both template code and a back-end controller (similar to "snippets" in the LiftWeb framework).

I am aware that there is a menu module for Play, but I'm more interested in how this would be achieved in general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to include common view code into the Play Framework.

You can use the `#{include}` tag or the `#{extends}` tag.

The extends tag, as the name suggests, extends from a parent view. The extends tag is used by default in the skeleton code set up by Play when you create a new application. It extends the main.html. You add your code here.

The includes tag, allows you to inject a common piece of view code into your templates at a specified point. This works in much the same was a php include/require, or jsp includes work.

The problem will come when your template code also requires data or logic from the model (via the controller). If this is the case, then you will need to use the @Before or @With notation in your controller to ensure that the common piece of controller code is executed each time. You can add any data to the renderArgs list, so that it is available for use within the view.

A simple example of using renderArgs would be.

```
@Before
private static void commonData() {
    // do your logic here
    renderArgs.put("menu", menu);
    renderArgs.put("selected", selectedMenuItem);
}
```

the values you have put into renderArgs (menu and selected in the example) will be available just in the same way as if you passed them into the render method.

Comment: Thank you - can you point me to any example code that uses renderArgs?

Comment: @Codemwnci I'm getting empty/null values in my renderArgs{}. On successfull login i stored a map in renderArgs and it printed with all values in console using renderArgs.get(login_det').toString(). When i use the same in another controller i'm getting renderArgs as {}.What could be the issue here.

Comment: is it part of the same action? Are you storing the data in renderArgs using @Before? Remember, renderArgs only lives for the length of the request, so it will be lost by the next request. Also remember that if you call another action from within an action it will force an HTTP redirect, which is another request, so renderArgs is reset.

Comment: @Codemwnci I set the values in a during login and in a seperate function which is <pre>@</pre>Before
private static void commonData() {
        Map cacheMap = Cache.get("login_det",Map.class);

        if(cacheMap!=null)
        {
         renderArgs.put("login_det", cacheMap);
         System.out.println("commonData"+renderArgs.toString());
    }
}

Comment: @Codemwnci in my customersList controller function i printed cache and renderArgs.toString(). Cahce still has values but renderArgs is {}

Comment: if you set the values in the login action, this will only live for that request. Cache on the other hand is intended to allow items to live for multiple requests.