# Multiple views for 1 controller - Play Framework

Tags: html, layout, view, tags, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Play Framework support “snippets”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797752/does-play-framework-support-snippets)

I've just started making a website using the Play Framework, but i've run into a problem.

I'am having a problem with properly setting up my layout, my layout currently looks like this:

```
main.html -> main markup of the page (includes header, body, etc...)

/templates/header.html -> got includes to components (eg. show username is logged in etc)
/templates/body.html -> this will be extended by the controller "view" 
/templates/footer.html -> Also dynamic (data from database)

/components/Navigation.html
/components/userloggedin.html
/components/somemorerandomcomponents
```

The problem i'am having is, i include the header, body and the footer into the main.html. When i call the controller the body gets rendered and "printend" in the body.html. But i want the header and footer to be rendered each call aswell, How can i achieve this in Play?

I prefer not to use inline code, so i prefer to call an object which returns the data(eg. username etc.). I've read something about Tags and i was wondering if that is what iam looking for (couldn't really figure it out) and if so, can someone please quickly explain how to implement them?

Thanks!

EDIT::

What i would like to have is the following: 
lets take the header.html as example. I want the header.html to be filled with dynamic "data", data retreived from a database.

I really dont wanna use inline java code to connect to a databas etc, that is why i was wondering if i can call some sort of object from within my view to fill the header.html with the dynamic generated content.

I've did some more research and maybe the way to go is, to make an Header model object and inject that into the template and then call that object in the view like:

```
#{header.Name /}
```

and inject it like:

```
render(header, body, footer);
```

Please correct me if iam wrong thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. If you are using the extends tag, or the include tag, then your code will be generated dynamically each time the view is called. I think we need to see some more code to find out your particular issue

Comment: Can u please have look at my edit? Thanks

Comment: I think I understand now. See this question and answer, which should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797752/does-play-framework-support-snippets

Comment: Thanks man!, Really appreciate it! If you could somehow make this an answer i can upvote you! Thanks once again!

Comment: The other answer is mine as well, so just up vote that if you like.