# How do I add dynamic content to main.html outside of doLayout in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I have dynamic content that I would like to display on every page in my application. I'm only using one template(main.html). I can render the content for every controller and then main.html has access to it, but I figure there has to be a cleaner way to include content outside of the doLayout tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to do this, is to use a @Before interceptor in your controller to get the dynamic elements, and to store it in the renderArgs, and then to place the dynamic content in your view by editing the main.html.

I think the question answers your question succinctly - [Does Play Framework support "snippets"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797752/does-play-framework-support-snippets).

Answer (score 0):

As doLayout is a custom tag, you can create a new one of your own and have any content you need, within your logic.

- [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#tags)

Comment: Actually I think you don't control custom tags from Controller side, but from views. You create one in: /views/tags/pastEvents.html, and in any file (even main.html) you call: #{pastEvents /}

Comment: Please have a look play framework's very good samples and demos, especially /forum/app/view/tags/pagination.html or showPost.html